# Multiple immutable changes on state arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, immutability

I have the following `currentState`. When i add the recipient, the new recipient should be appended to recipient.allIds and recipientProduct with default qty = 1. I am stuck at appending to the `recipientProduct` part. This should be done in `immutable way` as it is a redux state.

```
let currentState = {
  product: {
    allIds: ['1', '5'],
  },
  recipient: {
    allIds: ['1'],
  },
  recipientProduct: [{
        recipientId: '1',
        productId: '1',
        qty: '3'
    }, {
        recipientId: '1',
        productId: '5',
        qty: '3'
    }],
};
```

When I append a new recipient:

```
addRecipient = (recipientId) => {
    // when recipientId = 2
    // note quantity is always default to 1

    -> append productIds to product.allIds if not exists
    -> loop through all product from product.allIds
         loop through all recipient from recipient.allIds
         if (recipientId === recipientId && productId === productId) {
              remain
          } else {
            // append with default qty 1
        }

}
```

This will be the `newState`:

```
newstate = {
    product: {
        allIds: ['1', '5'],
    },
    recipient: {
        allIds: ['1', '2'],
    },
    recipientProduct: [{
        recipientId: '1',
        productId: '1',
        qty: '3'
    }, {
        recipientId: '1',
        productId: '5',
        qty: '3'
    },{
        recipientId: '2',
        productId: '1',
        qty: '1'
    }, {
        recipientId: '2',
        productId: '5',
        qty: '1'
    }],
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this item `{recipientId: 1 productId: '5', qty: '3'}` added to the recipientProduct?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov there is 2 object added to `recipientProduct` because there is 2 productId in product.allIds ['1', '5']. So i need to get it back all the `productIds` and thus produce    `{recipientId: '2',
        productId: '1',
        qty: '1'
    }, {
        recipientId: '2',
        productId: '5',
        qty: '1'
    }` which is 1 for productId 1 and another for 5

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov does that make clear to you ? It is normalized based on a multi recipient to multi product relationship

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov you could refer to `When I append a new recipient` logic session that i provided in my question.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes, u are right about that. That is a mistake on my inititialSate. I have updated that to provide a correct `initialState`

Comment: @vincentsty : you might want to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59679753/11299053) below, it follows canonical Redux pattern to update the state in immutable manner through dispatching actions to reducer. Live-demo included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a reducer that should handle the logic being described, not an action creator (?) `addRecipient`.

So, as I understood, in common Redux workflow you need to modify global state properties `recipient` (new recipient should be pushed in) and `recipientProduct` (items that correspond to each product with default quantity of 1 should be appended) upon dispatching `APPEND_RECIPIENT` action or such.

My solution for that would be the following:

```
appReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case 'APPEND_RECIPIENT' : {
            let {payload: recipientId} = action,
                  {recipient:{allIds:recipientIds}, recipientProduct, product:{allIds:productIds}} = state
            if(recipientIds.includes(recipientId)) return state
            recipientIds = [...recipientIds, recipientId]
            recipientProduct = [...recipientProduct,...productIds.map(productId => ({productId, recipientId, qty: '1'}))]
            return {...state, recipient:{allIds:recipientIds}, recipientProduct}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      }
```

You may find the live-demo of that concept below:

```js
//dependencies
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux

//initial state, reducer and store
const initialState = {product:{allIds:['1','5']},recipient:{allIds:['1']},recipientProduct:[{recipientId:'1',productId:'1',qty:'3'},{recipientId:'1',productId:'5',qty:'3'}]},
      appReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case 'APPEND_RECIPIENT' : {
            let {payload: recipientId} = action,
                  {recipient:{allIds:recipientIds}, recipientProduct, product:{allIds:productIds}} = state
            if(recipientIds.includes(recipientId)) return state
            recipientIds = [...recipientIds, recipientId]
            recipientProduct = [...recipientProduct,...productIds.map(productId => ({productId, recipientId, qty: '1'}))]
            return {...state, recipient:{allIds:recipientIds}, recipientProduct}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)
      
//append recipient form ui component
const AppendRecipient = ({onAppendRecipient, onInput}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInput] = useState()
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => (e.preventDefault(), onAppendRecipient(inputValue))}>
      <input type="number" onKeyUp={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="submit" name="Append Recipient" />
    </form>
  )
}
//connect onAppendRecipient handler to dispatching 'APPEND_RECIPIENT' action
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        onAppendRecipient: recipientId => dispatch({type:'APPEND_RECIPIENT', payload:recipientId})
      }),
      AppendRecipientContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AppendRecipient)
//mirroring recipientProducts
const RecipientProducts = ({products, productsQty}) => (
  <div>
    {
      products.map(({recipientId,productId,qty},key) => <div {...{key}}>recipient:{recipientId}, product:{productId}, qty: {qty}</div>)
    }
  </div>
)
//connect output element to global recipientProducts
const mapStateToProps = ({recipientProduct}) => ({products:recipientProduct, productsQty:recipientProduct.length}),
      RecipientProductsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipientProducts)
      
//render the entire app
render (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppendRecipientContainer />
    <RecipientProductsContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.3/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I see all the answer use `push` instead of `concat`. Why is `push` is chosen over `concat` here since `push` is mutable whereas `concat` is immutable

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this logic?

```js
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;

const ADD_RECIPIENT = "ADD_RECIPIENT";

const initialState = {
  product: {
    allIds: ["1", "5"]
  },
  recipient: {
    allIds: ["1"]
  },
  recipientProduct: [
    {
      recipientId: "1",
      productId: "1",
      qty: "3"
    },
    {
      recipientId: "1",
      productId: "5",
      qty: "3"
    }
  ]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_RECIPIENT:
      const recipientId = action.recipientId;
      const recipientExists = state.recipient.allIds.includes(recipientId);

      if (!recipientExists) {
        let recipientProducts = [...state.recipientProduct];

        state.product.allIds.forEach(productId => {
          let productIdExists =
            state.recipientProduct.findIndex(r => r.productId === productId) >-1;
          let recipientIdExists =
            state.recipientProduct.findIndex( r => r.recipientId === recipientId) > -1;

          if (!productIdExists || !recipientIdExists) {
            recipientProducts.push({recipientId,productId,qty: "1"});
          }
        });

        return {
          ...state,
          recipient: {
            allIds: [...state.recipient.allIds, recipientId]
          },
          recipientProduct: recipientProducts
        };
      }

      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("[NEW STATE]", store.getState());
});

store.dispatch({
  type: ADD_RECIPIENT,
  recipientId: "2"
});
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov maybe it is unnecessary, but better to safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of your current state.Modify your object and again assign that object to state.

```
addRecipient = (recipientId) => {
    let copy = {...currentState};
    copy.recipient.allIds.push(recipientId);
    copy.product.allIds.map((product)=>{
      let obj = {
        recipientId: recipientId,
        productId: product,
        qty: '1'
      }
      copy.recipientProduct.push(obj);
    });
    //Now `copy` is your new state.Old object will be as it is.
    //You can do anything with new object.
}
```

If you are using redux then you can call action or setState and can change the state.
Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: You are doing things in mutable way, not immutable

Comment: Then don't set it again using setState method or action of redux-store.All other things you can do.It will add your product and will give you update object then you can do any thing with new object.I have updated my answer.